# Firebase admin sdk calling the wrong catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am trying to add a new user with `firebase-admin` and then to save a new document in a custom collection.

Sample code following:

```
admin.auth().createUser(user)

    .then((record) => {

       user.uid = record.uid;

       userCollection.doc(record.uid).set({...user})

           .then(writeResult => {
               resolve();
           })
           .catch(reason => {
               reject(reason)
           });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
    });
```

The problem is, if the `userCollection.doc(record.uid).set({...user})` fails, I expect the nested catch (with `reason` as param) to be called. Instead, always the outer one is called (with `err` as param).

Is there something wrong with the SDK or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you don't return the promise returned by `userCollection.doc(record.uid).set()` and therefore you don't return the promises returned by the subsequent `then()` and `catch()` methods. In other words you don't return the [promises chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining).

But, actually, you should chain your Promises as follows and avoid a `then()/catch()` pyramid.

```
  admin
    .auth().createUser(user)
    .then((record) => {
      user.uid = record.uid;

      return userCollection
        .doc(record.uid)
        .set({ ...user })
    })
    .catch((err) => {

      // Here you catch the potential errors of 
      // the createUser() AND set() methods

      console.log(JSON.stringify(err));

    });
```

---

More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) and [here](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm going to read more about chaining but I have a question, with your code how can I understand what went wrong if the catch method is called?

Comment: Look at the update. The usual way is to analyze the `err` object. Here I've just logged it with `console.log(JSON.stringify(err));` but you can get the `message` or `code` property of this object and act accordingly.

Comment: For example, the error codes returned by the `createUser()` method are listed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors).

Comment: Ok, obviously that's a solution but I think could be a problem with a bigger project with more and more nested promises.. Wouldn't it be better to manage everything catch separately?

Comment: The best practice is to avoid the `then()/catch()` pyramid. More explanations [here](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining#example-loadscript). In other words, with Promises we can avoid the callbacks pyramid which can become a nightmare, *especially with large projects*, so you probably don't want to construct another pyramid with Promises ;-)